# Combine FFmpeg commands

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg, shell

How do you combine these FFmpeg commands?

```
    // Add Pad to video
    ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf pad=width=100:height=100:x=0:y=0:color=black output.mp4

    // Extract image at 10 seconds from the video
    ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:10.000 -vframes 1 output.jpg

    // Extract image at 30 seconds from the video
    ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:30.000 -vframes 1 output.jpg
```

The docs for these commands are at:

FFmpeg image extracting: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video

FFmpeg pad:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-73

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain the outputs:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf pad=width=100:height=100:x=0:y=0:color=black output.mp4
                    -ss 00:00:10.000 -vframes 1 output1.jpg
                    -ss 00:00:30.000 -vframes 1 output2.jpg
```